# Mediawiki doesn't use wikiEditor

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I've added the following line in my LocalSettings.php:

```
wfLoadExtension( 'WikiEditor' );
$wgHiddenPrefs[] = 'usebetatoolbar';
```

And yet, when I try to edit a page, I get an ugly editor like:

[image: Ugly Editor]

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?!

Comment: Just because you hide the opt-in preference, it does not automatically become enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

`wfLoadExtension( 'WikiEditor' );
$wgHiddenPrefs[] = 'usebetatoolbar';
$wgDefaultUserOptions['showtoolbar'] = true;
$wgDefaultUserOptions['usebetatoolbar'] = 1;`

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation why your solution works with detail and an easy to follow instructions. If you feel your answer is correct do these things and re-edit. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Comment: I self host a MediaWiki website. I had the same problem and this is the solution. I would rather keep it simple. mic84 do you even admin a MediaWiki website?

Comment: It's not about whether it works, the point mic84 was getting at is that it is preferable to explain what the changes do and why that fixes the issue. It may be obvious to you, but it might not be to the next person who comes along :)

Comment: bertieb it slows me down.